# How can I search for e-mails by user in "To..." or "Cc..."?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013, search-folder

I know that I can create a search folder that finds all the messages from or to a given user in Microsoft Outlook 2013.

How can I create a search folder that finds all messages that a given user was included in as "*Cc...*" or "*Bcc...*" in Microsoft Outlook 2013?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create a new Search Folder and select **Create a custom Search Folder** from the **Custom** category.
2. Click **Choose...** to specify criteria.

   [image]
3. In the resulting dialog, click **Criteria...**.
4. In the **Search Folder Criteria** dialog, switch to the **Advanced** tab.
5. In the **Field** dropdown, under **All Mail fields**, you'll find the **Cc** and **Bcc** fields which will allow you to define the search you want.

   [image]

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you for the detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a folder to hold all of those messages then right click on "inbox" and create a new folder.  Then create a rule that grabs all email where the email name is in the cc or bcc box.  That way every time Outlook sees that in the BCC or CC field it will move it automatically.  Here's a good article on creating a rule that automatically moves a message based on "something"

http://its.uiowa.edu/support/article/100835

Comment: I don't want to move the messages into a folder. This is more of a temporary search rather than a desire to always have these files together in the same folder.